# htaccess for url routing

Tags: url, parameters, routes

So I have htaccess routing rewrite rules listed below:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?urlredirect=$1&q=$3 [L]
```

But I am unable add more parameters as for example index.php?urlredirect=news&q=author**&rank=top**